# cannot convert void to list, return a sorted list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I want to return a sorted list but it gives me this error. What should I do?

```
public class sortA : sortMethod
{
    public override List<int> Sort(List<int> A)
    {
        //List<int> Asorted = new List<int>();
        //Asorted = A.Sort(){ };
        return A.Sort();
    }
}
```

Comment: a.Sort(); return a;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning `A.Sort` does not return the sorted array, it returns the `Sort` command's return value. Since `Sort` is a `void` method, it actually returns nothing, hence the error message.

So to return the sorted array, you need to return it **after** you sort it:

```
public class sortA : sortMethod
{
    public override List<int> Sort(List<int> A)
    {
        A.Sort();
        return A;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that `Sort` is a method which does not return a value. This is the main reason of the error.

Comment: This is nitpicking, but isn't is usually better to create a copy of the array given in the parameters? In order to keep the List A unsorted.

Answer (score 3):

> The [`List<T>.Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) method Sorts the elements in the entire List
>   using the default comparer. And the return type of the method is void.

*Why you are getting error*:

In your case the method `Sort` expect a return value of type `List<Int>`, But you are returning `A.Sort()` which actually returns nothing. This is the reason for the error.

*What you can do :*

After calling the `A.Sort()` the list `A` became sorted. Now you can return `A`. the modified code will be:

```
public override List<int> Sort(List<int> A)
{       
    A.Sort();
    return A;
}
```