# Trouble sorting a generic c# List (can have tuples, KeyValuePairs etc)

Tags: c#, list, generics, tuples, key-value

I'm trying create a method that will sort any kind of generic List.

I'm starting with a double and have a construction already for other types, but even with a double I'm having issues as D below doesn't exist in the current context.

I also have the feeling I'm over complicating this.
Any suggestions?

```
    public List<T> sortlist<T>(List<T> readlist)
    {

            if (readlist[0].GetType().Name.Substring(0, 5) == "Double")
            {
                var tlist = readlist as List<double>;
                var list =  tlist.OrderByDescending(d => D); //D here doesn't exist
              
            }
    

return sorted;
```

}

Edit:
I'm trying to use .Sort() as suggested, but an error that it cannot convert from void to GenericList is showing up.

Using .Sort doesn't return a List and is instead void?

I'm a bit new to this and lost. Any documentation for newbies is welcome as well (altought what I've found so far is not easily implemented)

Kind regards,

Edit2:
Found a solution here: [cannot convert void to list, return a sorted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879585/cannot-convert-void-to-list-return-a-sorted-list)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need such a method at all? Simply `List<T>.Sort()` will sort a list perfectly using default comparer for `T`. And there is also an overloads where you can provide you own comparer. What problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It sounds like the solution is to have your collectible classes implement IComparable, not implement a method.

Comment: As @Serg wrote - `List<T>` already has a `Sort()` method. Why would you want to write your own?

Comment: Because I might want to sort by the 2nd or 3rd element of a tuple for example, or by the Value of KeyValuePair. But indeed with these comments I realize indeed I'm over complicating, I'll research a bit more into it.

Comment: "sort by the 2nd or 3rd element of a tuple for example" - .NET 8 will have [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) which makes things a lot easier (no need for custom comparers)

Answer (score 0):

The [`Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-8.0) method is decoupled from the comparer - meaning you can use whatever comparison logic you want with the already existing `Sort()` method.
There are four overloads for `Sort()`:

> `Sort(Comparison<T>)` Sorts the elements in the entire `List<T>` using the specified [`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=net-8.0).

> `Sort(Int32, Int32, IComparer<T>)` Sorts the elements in a range of elements in `List<T>` using the specified [comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=net-8.0).

> `Sort()` Sorts the elements in the entire `List<T>` using the [default comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1.default?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-comparer-1-default).

> `Sort(IComparer<T>)` Sorts the elements in the entire `List<T>` using the specified [comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=net-8.0).

Note that `Comparison<T>` is a delegate which means you can use a lambda expression for it - for instance:

```
myList.Sort((a, b) => a.SomeProperty.CompareTo(b.SomeProperty));
```